# Invalid column name 'level'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am having trouble adding a column to my table, it seems simple so I don't understand why I am getting this error. To add the column in SQL I used the following Query:

```
ALTER TABLE [Trades]
ADD level nvarchar(max)
```

To add to the model I added:

```
    public string level { get; set; }
```

to public class trade.

What could the issue be?

edit: Here is the full error:

```
Invalid column name 'level'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'level'.

Source Error: 
Line 20:         {
Line 21:             ViewBag.Name = Name;
Line 22:             return View(db.Movies.ToList());
Line 23:         }
Line 24:
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about the environment you are trying to do this in? I thought the problem was that 'level' was a reserved tqsl keyword, and needed the square brackets. However, I just tried running the create column with no square brackets both on local and azure hosted sql server (from SSMS), and they worked. Either way - try the square brackets, might help.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tried it with square brackets but it is giving me "Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'level' in table 'Trades' is specified more than once." It looks to me like the value added to the database just fine. I am running the SQL server and website through Azure, it's MVC 4 using C#.

Comment: How do you retrieve the data from the database? show your `Data Access` code.

Comment: did you update your `.edmx` file to reflect the change in the database. and also in your web.config did you update the connection string in the `<connectionStrings>` section.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SQL Server Instance, `Level` is a reserved keyword. (Used when changing the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION` for example.

Try change the property name to something else, or add a ColumnName attribute to the property, to map it to a different SQL Column.

e.g. Create a column on your table with

```
ALTER TABLE [Trades]
ADD LevelProperty nvarchar(max)
```

and use the following decorator on your EF POCO

```
[Column("LevelProperty")]
public string Level { get; set; }
```